How to get Revit data model after user click Synchronize with Central
How can we use Autodesk Platform Services API to get data when the user use Synchronize with Central without Publish the model ?

I want to get early stage of enginnering data before they Publish the model. I want know Where is data sent after the user click the button, and how can we get that?
Any help is appreciated !

To get the synced model content before publishing the cloud model, we can only open the synced model with Revit Desktop or Design Automation using Revit Cloud Model API, like the normal operations on Cloud worksharing model.
var cloudModelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(inputParams.Region, inputParams.ProjectGuid, inputParams.ModelGuid);
Document doc = rvtApp.OpenDocumentFile(cloudModelPath, new OpenOptions());

ref: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-api-supports-revit-cloud-model

Hi Kason Kang, is it posible to tracking event webhook the user synce central ?

https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/revit_cloud_worksharing_events/model.sync/

Thank you @Eason Kang, that is correct what I'm need now !
